# IPython Notebook - ShimWarning: The `IPython.kernel` package has been deprecated

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I am receiving the following message when importing some packages into IPython-Notebook:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

//anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/kernel/__init__.py:13: ShimWarning: The `IPython.kernel` package has been deprecated. You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.
  "You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.", ShimWarning)
```

[image]

This does not seem to affect the results but I would like to resolve this error. I understood from some of the post here that this problem will cause IPython-Notebook to stop working when upgrading to Python 4. I am running IPython Notebook version 4.0.4 via Anaconda on Mac OSX 10.11.1.

I must admit that I am not very savvy with python package installation but I need to use this for school and thought this would a nice way to learn this stuff.

Comment: Sounds pretty self-explanatory to me. Some module, probably `scipy.integrate.odeint` is importing the deprecated module `IPython.kernel` package, which has moved to `ipykernel`. The problem likely lies in `scipy`; update it or wait for them to fix it.

Comment: Before posting this question, I tried it without importing scipy.integrate.odeint and I still get the message (in fact I tried importing each package by itself and other packages). As I said in my question I am new to Python development so it is not "pretty self-explanatory" to me.  I saw some discussion on this on GitHub but it does not appear resolved yet. I downloaded the latest version of Anaconda so not sure how to "update it". Also I did not get this error before today. I have not updated or installed anything new since the last time I used IPython-Notebook.

Comment: I did not have `numpy` and `scipy` installed and I still saw this message while running `help('modules')`... Nor did I have `matplotlib`...

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar warning that was caused by the line:

```
%matplotlib notebook
```

To remove the warning update to the latest version of matplotlib (updating to 1.5.0 solved it in my case). If you use pip, then

```
pip install -U matplotlib
```

Answer (score 2):

I was seeing the same warning (albeit with Python 3.5) and found a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/290#issuecomment-133556814) about it from August 2015; there you can find a more complete explanation and a command likely to fix this:

`jupyter kernelspec install-self --user`

As a comment on the original question suggests, this is indeed a problem of a deprecated IPython kernel command. I'm not sure how universal a fix it is, but that thread explains what it's doing quite well!

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue while running

```
help("modules")
```

The following fixed it:

```
from jupyter_client.manager import KernelManager
```

Found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46547759/1457380)

Config: Python 3.8.1 in May 2020

Comment: I'm using `py3.8.8`, when I tried those two lines, I got warning `WARNING: AstropyDeprecationWarning: The private astropy._erfa module has been made into its own package, pyerfa, which is a dependency of astropy and can be imported directly using "import erfa" [astropy._erfa]`

Answer (score 0):

Try updating numpy. You're probably using an old version.

From the command line it is

```
conda update numpy
```