# How to replace "from IPython.kernel import KernelManager"?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have some code which tries to import a `KernalManager` from `IPython`, but I get a Warning

```
/home/alex/Projects/VETests/ipyrunner/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/__init__.py:13: ShimWarning: The `IPython.kernel` package has been deprecated since IPython 4.0.You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.
  "You should import from ipykernel or jupyter_client instead.", ShimWarning)
```

but when I do the following

```
from ipykernel import KernelManager
```

I get an error

```
ImportError: cannot import name KernelManager
```

How to do it right?

Comment: Are you actually explicitly importing the KernelManager? If not, the warning is most likely stemming from an outdated matplotlib notebook backend?

Comment: I only know that in the actual code the KernelManager is tried to be imported by `from IPython.kernel import KernelManager`.

Comment: Sounds awfully vague. You do not have access to the code? -- Anyway, I will then assume that for whatever undisclosed reason you are explicitly trying to import the kernelmanager (which I'd advise against).. the update to IPython 4.0 changed from `IPython.kernel` to `ipykernel`. So probably trying to import a `KernelManager` is not going to work. `from jupyter_client.manager import KernelManager` is the correct depth for jupyter_client import. `from ipykernel import kernelapp` you can also try...but I'm out of my depth here -- especially as long as I don't know the details.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to run this code: https://gist.github.com/minrk/2620735

Comment: No idea what a 'kernel' is for in this context, or how all this jupyter stuff works...

Comment: okay. Can you try exchanging `from ipykernel import KernelManager` to `from jupyter_client.manager import KernelManager` ?

Comment: Yes, that seems to work...   thanks

Comment: Added it as answer for that particular reason. Glad to be of help -- dealing with outdated example codes can always be a hassle. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Replace

`from IPython.kernel import KernelManager`/`from ipykernel import KernelManager`

with

`from jupyter_client.manager import KernelManager`.